# What happens to the methanol formed by the hydrolysis of methyl 2-hydroxybenzoate (oil of wintergreen) when synthesising salicylic acid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

Here are the reaction equations for reference *(you may recognise this as a preliminary step for the synthesis of aspirin)*.

Steps for synthesis of salicylic acid:

1) methyl 2-hydroxybenzoate + sodium hydroxide -> sodium 2-hydroxybenzoate + **methanol**

2) sodium 2-hydroxybenzoate + hydrochloric acid -> salicylic acid + sodium chloride

Does the methanol play an underlying role in the reaction somewhere? Is the methanol filtered off? I do not know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methanol plays no underlying role in the reaction

Without more detail of the reaction procedure I cannot give a complete answer, but my expectation is that after the HCl addition the reaction will be quenched by addition of water to either precipitate the salicylic acid or then be extracted into an immiscible organic solvent. The methanol will stay in the aqueous phase in either case.

Comment: Reaction mixture is heated under reflux and then allowed to cool; then the mixture is filtered under reduced pressure. Your answer supports this, thank you.

Comment: I presume that the HCl is added after the refluxed mixture is allowed to cool. If you are happy with the answer, please accept it